# Weighted Least squares with Multiple Unknowns and Iterations

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I am currently working on a problem involving the minimization of the $\chi^2$ deviation between a model matrix ($C_\text{model}$) and a measured matrix ($C_\text{measured}$). by finding the best-fit parameters values: $\Delta g,$ $\Delta x,$ $\Delta y,$ and $\Delta p_\ell$ by performing iterations.

The minimization problem:

$$  \chi^2 =\sum_{i,j} C^2_{i,j} =\sum_{i,j} \frac{(C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j})^2}{\sigma^2_i} = \sum_{i,j} (C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j})^2 W_i $$

And:

$$ C_{\text{model},i,j} = \hat{C}_{i,j} + \sum_k \frac{\partial \hat{C}_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k+ \hat{C}_{i,j} \, \Delta x^i -\hat{C}_{i,j} \, \Delta y^j + \sum_\ell \frac{\partial \hat{C}_{i,j}}{\partial p_\ell} \, \Delta p_\ell $$

where:

$C_{\text{model}}$ : $i \times j$ matrices

$C_{\text{measured}}$ : $i \times j$ matrices

$\sigma_i$ : vector of length $i$

$\Delta x^i$ : vector of length $i$

$\Delta y^i$ : vector of length $j$

$\Delta g_k$ : vector of length $k$

I have tried to solve this problem before with only one unknown $\Delta g_k$ as following:

$$(C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j}) = \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k$$
$$  \chi^2 = \left|(C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j})-\sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k \right|^2 $$
$$  \chi^2_w = \left| (C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j})-\sum_k \frac{\partial{C_{i,j}}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k\right|^T W\left|(C_{\text{model},i,j} -\hat{C}_{i,j})-\sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k\right|$$
$$ \frac{\partial \chi^2_w}{\partial g_k} = 2 \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k}^T W \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \, \Delta g_k - 2 \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} W (C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j}) =0$$

$$ \left(\sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \partial g_k\right)^T W \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \partial g_k = \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} W(C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j})$$

$$  \Delta g_k = \left( \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k}^T W\frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} \right)^{-1} \sum_k \frac{\partial C_{i,j}}{\partial g_k} W(C_{\text{model},i,j}-\hat{C}_{i,j}) $$

However in the problem i am working in the model and measured matrices are not liner in the fit parameters so it Saied the the solution must be iterated until it converges.

Starting from my solution in one variable can some one please explain to me how to extend the problem to include many unknowns, by performing iterations.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755097/weighted-least-squares-with-multiple-unknowns-and-iterations

Comment: In some ways this looks somewhat like the usual chi-square test of independence of two categorical random variables, although this seems quite a bit more elaborate. In particular, the quantity $C_{\text{model},i,j}$ is a certain function of the "measured" quantities. I don't understand what division by $\sigma_i^2$ can mean if $\sigma_i$ is a "vector of length $i.$" I'm not sure I'll ever understand this without some explanation of where this model comes from.

Comment: I wonder whether you meant that $\sigma_i$ is the $i\text{th}$ component of a vector of length equal to the number of values of $i$ that occur.

Comment: Maybe this question would fare better on stats.stackexchange.com .